How can I restrict AWS resource access to specific Cognito users?
Each Cognito user has their own S3 bucket and I want to grant them and only them access to it.
My current approach is I have a user pool and an identity pool, and I'm using an authenticated role for the identity pool with the following policy attached:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName-${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        }
    ]
}

This works fine if I make the bucket name using the identity id. However, I am using API Gateway to trigger my Lambda function that creates the bucket, and I call the API using a JWT token from my user pool, so in the Lambda function I don't have access to the identity id in the context (only the user id).
My question is there a way to secure access to the S3 bucket using the user id instead of the identity id? Or can I use the user id to get the identity id in my Lambda function? Or do I have to just switch to using the identity pool to call the Lambda function directly instead of using API Gateway?
Thanks for the help!

It is not recommended to create a "bucket per user". It is preferable to use a single bucket and grant access within the bucket. For an example, see: Amazon S3: Allows Amazon Cognito users to access objects in their bucket - AWS Identity and Access Management

In my case each bucket is being used to host a website. If I were to use just one bucket all the sites would be hosted in there. Is that possible?

If you were wanting multiple hosted websites, each with their own custom URL, it would not be easy in S3 (it would involve a lot of redirection). But, please note there are limits to the number of buckets that AWS will assign to your account. The default is 1000. You can ask for more, but no guarantees more will be given. If you do not need each website to have a custom domain, then you can certainly host them all from one bucket, each with their own path (eg mywebsite.com/user1/index.htm).
